# How to append xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" to my CMS's html tag

Tags: jquery, facebook, append, xml-namespaces

I want to know how I can add these attributes to my html tag that gets auto generated by our closed CMS system.

I would like to add to our current html tag:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

To this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Is there any way to do this using JQuery?

Comment: Yes.. there are closed CMS systems out there and where I work we happen to have our site on this platform. It does some things well but its just too closed of a system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $("html").attr("xmlns:og","http://ogp.me/ns#");
}
```

It's rare that XML namespace attributes in your HTML tag have any relevance on page behavior.

Comment: @Matthew, if you inspect the DOM with a tool like Firebug or Chrome's developer tools, it "works" but practically speaking it doesn't "do" anything to whatever you're trying to effect because it's not present on page load. Odds are if this is affecting one of your plugins like Facebook, you'd have to rerun the initialization routines after you make the DOM change.

Comment: No your right... its just not going to function properly. Thing is i'm trying to get around having to get charged for having this namespace added to our CMS.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the namespace declaration to the  element, but as I recall you can't use the DOM to add namespace mappings. 
JQuery uses js-DOM under the covers to manipulate the elements.
You should find the code that renders the html element and add it there.

In the past, when I needed to do that in .net / java I had to render the DOM Document Element out to a string and add the xmlns="attr" with a string concatonation, then reparse the string to DOM.

This method will not work in JS though.

Comment: Problem is this CMS system that we are on is a closed CMS... so i'm trying to figure out how to get those namespaces added.

Comment: My answer was correct to your original question, but what CMS are you using? What language is it written in? I can provide a hack in a several frameworks to get this to work.